# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory - missing sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm trying to test my REST API, with Hibernate and H2, and I'm getting PersistenceException :
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

```
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at pl.edu.polsource.HibernateTest.init(HibernateTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateSequence(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    ... 19 more
```

Here are my test files, problem occures in line

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
```

in:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    protected static EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void initializeDatabase() {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                try {
                    File script = new File(getClass().getResource("/data.sql").getFile());
                    RunScript.execute(connection, new FileReader(script));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("could not initialize with script");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public class HibernateCRUDTest extends HibernateTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetObjectById_success() {
        Notes note = em.find(Notes.class, 1);
        assertNotNull(note);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAll_success() {

        List<Notes> note = em.createNamedQuery("Notes.getAll", Notes.class).getResultList();
        assertEquals(4, note.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersist_success() {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(new Notes("TestTitle", "Unit Test Hibernate/JPA with in memory H2 Database"));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        List<Notes> note = em.createNamedQuery("Notes.getAll", Notes.class).getResultList();

        assertNotNull(note);
        assertEquals(5, note.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDelete_success(){
        Notes note = em.find(Notes.class, 1);

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(note);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        List<Notes> notes = em.createNamedQuery("Notes.getAll", Notes.class).getResultList();


        assertEquals(0, notes.size());
    }
}
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- add classes -->
        <class>model.Notes</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
            <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:data.sql'"/>-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:/test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:data.sql'"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>

            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't know why I'm getting Schema-validation: missing sequence ;/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing sequence or table: hibernate\_sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561385/missing-sequence-or-table-hibernate-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

Simply set your `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=` to `none` in your property file instead of using the default value of `false`