# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [hibernate_sequence]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have updated the Spring and Hibernate version from 4.3.25.Release to 5.3.9 and 3.6.10.Final to 5.6.0.Final. As part of resolving issues, I have replaced the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean with LocalSessionFactoryBean because i am using hibernate 5 but iam getting below error while running a build and server.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/elsevier/sct/services/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [hibernate_sequence]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [hibernate_sequence]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
... 63 more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schema-validation: missing table \[hibernate\_sequences\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675714/schema-validation-missing-table-hibernate-sequences) or [missing sequence or table: `hibernate_sequence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561385/missing-sequence-or-table-hibernate-sequence)

Comment: No above solutions are not useful for my scenario. Here everything was correct and configured properly which are saying in above links. 
My Scenario is : I have upgraded the spring and hibernate version to latest and am getting compatibility issues with above error.

Comment: This may be the same problem as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659505/spring-boot-project-fails-to-run-because-of-schema-validation-missing-sequence